# eth.getBalance returning 0 due to syncing problem in rinkeby

Tags: go-ethereum, synchronization, rinkeby, fast-sync

when I am running `eth.syncing` it is returning `false` and when I am running `eth.getBlock("latest")` it is returning number: `8290864`, with some other data. Which is less than Block Height `8762197` fetched from https://blockexplorer.one/eth/rinkeby (I am assuming that rinkeby node is not completely synced yet). and therefore I am not able to fetch balance and sendTransaction via geth attach ipc.

I am running `nohup geth --rinkeby --syncmode "fast" --ipcpath "/home/ubuntu/.ethereum/rinkeby/geth.ipc" --cache=1024 &` to sync and run the rinkeby node.

In log file I am getting these two warnings repeatedly

```
WARN [06-14|11:22:41.622] Served parity_netPeers                   conn=62.182.82.30:44802  reqid=3 t="12.567µs" err="the method parity_netPeers does not exist/is not available"
WARN [06-14|11:22:41.622] Served admin_peers                       conn=62.182.82.30:44800  reqid=3 t="10.6µs"   err="the method admin_peers does not exist/is not available"
```

I looked for these warnings on internet, didn't found any usefull resource.

How do i fix it? please help.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: YOu may need to check your peer list and update that. it may have old peers that are not online anymore. or maybe you are running short of space on your disk.

Comment: @KakiMasterOfTime I checked the space and 40 GB space is available. How do I check the peer list and update it? I am new to ethereum.